# Reading from Cassandra using Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a problem when i use spark streaming to read from Cassandra.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md#reading-from-cassandra-from-the-streamingcontext

As the link above, i use

```
val rdd = ssc.cassandraTable("streaming_test", "key_value").select("key", "value").where("fu = ?", 3)
```

to select the data from cassandra, but it seems that the spark streaming has just one query once but i want it continues to query using an interval 10 senconds.

My code is as follow, wish for your response.

Thanks!

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue


object SimpleApp {
def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("scala_streaming_test").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

    val rdd = ssc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "users").select("fname", "lname").where("lname = ?", "yu")

    //rdd.collect().foreach(println)

    val rddQueue = new Queue[RDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]]()


    val dstream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)

    dstream.print()

    ssc.start()
    rdd.collect().foreach(println)
    rddQueue += rdd
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

}

Comment: could you describe what do you want to achieve? Read the full table on each interval? Where is the streaming data coming from?

Comment: @maasg  I want to read the table on each interval (such as 10s) to query some records which are related to the time. It means I want to let the Cassandra be the source of Spark Streaming.  In one word, I'm blocked at the creation of the DStream. Would you like to give some tips and example? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a ConstantInputDStream with the CassandraRDD as input. ConstantInputDStream will provide the same RDD on each streaming interval, and by executing an action on that RDD you will trigger a materialization of the RDD lineage, leading to executing the query on Cassandra every time.

Make sure that the data being queried does not grow unbounded to avoid increasing query times and resulting in an unstable streaming process.

Something like this should do the trick (using your code as starting point):

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ConstantInputDStream

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

val cassandraRDD = ssc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "users").select("fname", "lname").where("lname = ?", "yu")

val dstream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, cassandraRDD)

dstream.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
    // any action will trigger the underlying cassandra query, using collect to have a simple output
    println(rdd.collect.mkString("\n")) 
}
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: What if I only want to read **new data** saved to the table since the last RDD was processed? Is that possible?

Comment: is there a way to prevent old data to be fetch again? it keeps in a infinite loop.

Comment: @yurishkuro AFAIK that's currently not possible.

Comment: just pipe your data to kafka and then from there into Spark and if you need persistence dump it to Cassandra

Comment: The code accepted as solution here doesn't work at all. I tested it out; no compilation error, but it doesn't do anything either. No screaming data from Cassandra is happening.

Comment: @user1888243 note that this solution is to read the complete table every time, not to stream data from Cassandra. Check out the question details and clarifications in the comments.

Comment: @maasg what benefit we are getting by using spark streaming as the same can be done with spark batch job itself. Is their a way to stream live data of cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a solution by creating a subclass of InputDStream class. It is necessary to define `start()` and `compute()` methods.

`start()` can be used for preparation. The main logic resides in `compute()`. It shall return `Option[RDD[T]]`.
To make the class flexible, `InputStreamQuery` trait is defined.

```
trait InputStreamQuery[T] {
  // where clause condition for partition key
  def partitionCond : (String, Any)
  // function to return next partition key
  def nextValue(v:Any) : Option[Any]
  // where clause condition for clustering key
  def whereCond : (String, (T) => Any)
  // batch size
  def batchSize : Int
}
```

For the Cassandra table `keyspace.test`, create `test_by_date` which reorganizes the table by the partitioning key `date`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists keyspace.test
(id timeuuid, date text, value text, primary key (id))

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT exists keyspace.test_by_date AS
SELECT *
FROM  keyspace.test
WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (date, id)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( id ASC );
```

One possible implementation for `test` table shall be

```
class class Test(id:UUID, date:String, value:String)

trait InputStreamQueryTest extends InputStreamQuery[Test] {
  val dateFormat = "uuuu-MM-dd"

  // set batch size as 10 records
  override def batchSize: Int = 10

  // partitioning key conditions, query string and initial value
  override def partitionCond: (String, Any) = ("date = ?", "2017-10-01")
  // clustering key condition, query string and function to get clustering key from the instance
  override def whereCond: (String, Test => Any) = (" id > ?", m => m.id)
  // return next value of clustering key. ex) '2017-10-02' for input value '2017-10-01'
  override def nextValue(v: Any): Option[Any] = {

    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( dateFormat)
    val nextDate = LocalDate.parse(v.asInstanceOf[String], formatter).plusDays(1)
    if ( nextDate.isAfter( LocalDate.now()) ) None
    else Some( nextDate.format(formatter))
  }
}
```

It can be used in the `CassandraInputStream` class as follows.

```
class CassandraInputStream[T: ClassTag]
(_ssc: StreamingContext, keyspace:String, table:String)
(implicit rrf: RowReaderFactory[T], ev: ValidRDDType[T]) 
extends InputDStream[T](_ssc) with InputStreamQuery[T] {

var lastElm:Option[T] = None
var partitionKey : Any = _

override def start(): Unit = {

  // find a partition key which stores some records
  def findStartValue(cql : String, value:Any): Any = {
    val rdd  = _ssc.sparkContext.cassandraTable[T](keyspace, table).where(cql, value).limit(1)

    if (rdd.cassandraCount() > 0 ) value
    else {
      nextValue(value).map( findStartValue( cql, _)).getOrElse( value)
    }
  }
  // get query string and initial value from partitionCond method
  val (cql, value) = partitionCond
  partitionKey = findStartValue(cql, value)
}

override def stop(): Unit = {}

override def compute(validTime: Time): Option[RDD[T]] = {
  val (cql, _) = partitionCond
  val (wh, whKey) = whereCond

  def fetchNext( patKey: Any) : Option[CassandraTableScanRDD[T]] = {
    // query with partitioning condition
    val query = _ssc.sparkContext.cassandraTable[T](keyspace, table).where( cql, patKey)

    val rdd = lastElm.map{ x =>
      query.where( wh, whKey(x)).withAscOrder.limit(batchSize)
    }.getOrElse( query.withAscOrder.limit(batchSize))

    if ( rdd.cassandraCount() > 0 ) {
      // store the last element of this RDD
      lastElm = Some(rdd.collect.last)
      Some(rdd)
    }
    else {
      // find the next partition key which stores data
      nextValue(patKey).flatMap{ k =>
        partitionKey = k
        fetchNext(k)}
    }
  }

  fetchNext( partitionKey)
}
}
```

Combining all the classes,

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

val dstream = new CassandraInputStream[Test](ssc, "keyspace", "test_by_date") with InputStreamQueryTest

dstream.map(println).saveToCassandra( ... )

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```